# how to fix svn trunk; cannot find .svn-base error (subversion)

Tags: svn

When I try to check out trunk/ from one of the Subversion repos, the following error occurs (and only part of the repo is checked out):

```
In directory '...trunk\www\libs\jquery'
Can't open file '...trunk\www\libs\jquery\.svn\tmp\text-base\jquery.scrollTo.html.svn-base': 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have only trace midi-chlorians for the art of SVN maintenance and repair, as the control panel normally solves these issues for me. I have access to two resources which may be of great help:

1. a checkout of trunk synced to the lasted HEAD version
2. root SSH access to the new box, where trunk has been corrupted

What strategy should I take to solve this? What documentation do I need to read up on?

Is there some way to force my local copy into the repo and overwrite the existing content? Or am I going to be stuck with deleting the repo (i.e. losing version history) and creating a new one with the source?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a folder or something got removed using non-svn methods.  I have seen this error when  build script we had started removing a folder and its contents, then adding it back again.  But of course the .svn folder was missing.

Comment: Rob. I think that's exactly the case, or maybe just that one file. But I have no idea how to restore the repo to operational status.

Comment: The error you are getting looks like it is from your working copy, not the repo.  If you do a fresh checkout into a new working copy, do you get this message?

Comment: Yes, this is happening on a checkout; no local copy

Comment: Can you browse to the file it suggests in the error message using a repository browser of some kind?

Comment: I guess what I'd rather do, since I have access to the old repository, is find some way to manually migrate it over and replace the new/corrupted one. Is this something I could do with a tarball?

Comment: Scratch that; I just checked the old repo and it's also bad (I get a slap on the hand for not verifying my facts); I still have a local/current/complete copy I can get my hands on; would it be easier to restore that somehow? (I've updated question to match these discoveries)

Comment: If you believe the repository is bad, and you have a complete working copy.  you can export the working copy, or recursively remove all of the .svn folders from the source tree.  then do a Add to a new repository.  I would still try using a repository browser or something to ensure that the repo is bad as the error message really sounds like it is working copy related.  Could you be extracting the working copy to a filesystem that does not support the path lengths required by the repo contents?

Comment: I may do the add to new repo; I'm hoping for a way to save all the historical data. It doesn't seem to matter if I do the checkout on linux or windows, from the old server or new, so I'm fairly sure the actual repo got corrupted. Where's the magical "fixit" option at when you need it? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the entire repository from scratch by making a copy, deleting the repo, deleting all the .svn directories recursively, and importing a new repo :(